# AMPL param syntax

Tags: ampl

I'm struggling with AMPL syntax (it's my first project).
In my model I have:

```
set GRID; # a grid represented by a sequence of integer
param W; # width of the grid
param d{i in GRID, j in GRID}; # distance between point of the grid
```

in my data I have:

```
set GRID = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16;
param W = 4;
param d{i in GRID, j in GRID} = sqrt( (abs(i-j) mod W)**2 + (abs(i-j) div W)**2 ); # I want to calculate the distance between each pair of points
```

but on last line I get the error:

```
 (offset 7)
 expected ; ( [ : or symbol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMPL data format doesn't allow expressions, so you need to specify the initialization of the `d` parameter in the model itself:

```
set GRID; # a grid represented by a sequence of integer
param W; # width of the grid
param d{i in GRID, j in GRID} = sqrt((abs(i-j) mod W)**2 + (abs(i-j) div W)**2);
```